# Why are /dev/random and /dev/urandom stopping after 32MiB?

Tags: linux, shell, random, dd

I get this output on very single commandline listed below:

```
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
33554431 bytes (34 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.14532 s, 231 MB/s
```

Here are the different options I tried:

a) `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null status=progress bs=1G count=1`

b) `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress bs=1G count=1`

c) `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress bs=100M count=1`

d) `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress bs=50M count=1`

e) `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null status=progress bs=50M count=1`

f) `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null status=progress bs=33M count=1`

g) `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress bs=33M count=1`

This `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress bs=10M count=1` is doing as expected and outputs:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0518184 s, 202 MB/s
```

I tried this with MX Linux (Kernel 5.10) and with KDE neon and with Ubuntu 20.04

Does someone have a under-the-hod answer? Or some possible ideas?

Comment: `MX Linux (Kernel 5.10)` please post what architecture and the output of `uname -a`

Comment: @KamilCuk output of ```uname -a```: Linux mx1 5.10.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.106-1 (2022-03-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

From the [Linux man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html):

> Since Linux 3.16, a read(2) from /dev/urandom will return at most
> 32 MB

The reason has to do with the fact that it's a special character file interfacing with an underlying driver rather than a "regular" file. The underlying driver clamps the output size to 32 MB in this case. Another answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1388082/dd-is-producing-a-32-mb-random-file-instead-of-1-gb) provides more details on this matter.

Comment: It doesn't say anything explicitly about `/dev/random`, but my guess is that they share this detail in the underlying implementations

Comment: real /dev/random only supplies 16 bytes before you just get the PRNG output.  Most systems just link it to /dev/urandom.

Answer (score 0):

bs, the buffer size, means the size of a single read() call done by dd.

(For example, both bs=1M count=1 and bs=1k count=1k will result in a 1 MiB file, but the first version will do it in a single step, while the second will do it in 1024 small chunks.)

I came with solution that reads 32 chunks 32 MB large which makes 1GB:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output bs=32M count=32
```

Comment: If you want to copy/paste text from other people's answers, at least put it in a block quote and cite [your source](https://superuser.com/questions/1388082/dd-is-producing-a-32-mb-random-file-instead-of-1-gb#answer-1388090). Plagiarism is bad.